# Reading Excel/xls ,csv,ods file in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using paperclip to upload the (Excel/xls , csv, ods) files. Now i want to import the data from those files. Which gem to use ???

I am using gem spreadsheet but is there any alternate gem for doing so ??

Answer (score 0):

Use http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

For rail2: `gem install spreadsheet`

For rail3: `gem "spreadsheet", "~> 0.8.5"`

Hope this help